# How do I detect if a Window gets closed?

Tags: python

Ok I opened a .mp4 using

```py
import os
os.startfile('test.mp4')
```

How can I detect when the window (of the default Windows app used to show videos) gets closed to run the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with `startfile`.

From Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html):

> There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to retrieve the application’s exit status

You would need to use the `subprocess` module instead:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['start', 'test.mp4'])

# do other stuff
```

This command will not exit until the program you ran is closed.

Comment: i just tested it but it gives an error https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/ebded49fd1cd4f649032a3956e10ce56

Comment: @SRK7Kyros Sorry, but I don't have a windows computer to test this on. The Python part works, but maybe `start` does not work on your PC for some reason or there is a problem with the working directory. Try opening CMD and typing start test.mp4 see if that works. If it does not, you may need additional code to find the name of the media player and launch it directly.

Comment: If you're reading this it's probably because you saw your question accepted. actually I just used the module wrong, mb.